# Customized columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could you please check attached screens.

I had used Bootstrap columns like `col-lg-6` etc.

I need login section on top in mobile view only. How can I?

Desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLtle.jpg

Mobile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xukBx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap you can specify to hide hidden-xs and hidden-sm. this will hide the corresponding div or element to hide or show on specific sized screens.

Doing this technique you can hide a specific div on large screens (hidden-sm hidden-xs) then show the other login form in the new position using hidden-lg hidden-xl hidden-md.

I have used this several times for different pieces of work. I hope this helps.